# How to use <param> in launch files to change variable values in node scripts?

Tags: roslaunch, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use  in launch files to change variable values in node scripts but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>

  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/minimal.launch" />

  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/gmapping_demo.launch" />

  <include file="$(find frontier_exploration)/launch/global_map.launch" />

  <node name="send_exploration_goal" pkg="turtlebot_demos" type="send_exploration_goal"/>
     <param name="set_linear_vel" value="0.1" />
     <param name="set_angular_vel" value="0.1" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

And here is a skeleton of the node script:

```
#include ...

void function()
{ 
   ....
}

int main(int arcg, char** argv)
{
  ....
   float set_linear_vel = 0.25;
   float set_angular_vel = 0.50;
  ....
 }
```

1. My first question is, am I doing this right?
2. Second, does it matter where I define the variables in the node script?  Should they be defined as global variables, defined inside int main(), or inside void function()?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230370/how-to-use-%3Cparam%3E-in-launch-files-to-change-variable-values-in-node-scripts?/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use ROS parameters in your C++ code, you need to explicitly read those parameters into a variable.

I'd suggest you go through the [ROS C++ parameters tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Parameters)

When you declare a parameter with a `<param>` tag in a launch file, you're creating a private parameter within that node's namespace, so you should also read through the tutorial on private namespaces: [Accessing Private Names from a NodeHandle (roscpp)](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/AccessingPrivateNamesWithNodeHandle)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-03-28**:
Thanks! I didnt realize there was documentation for this.  I'll check it out.